# Facebook login: key hash does not match any stored key hashes

Tags: android, facebook, react-native

I am working on a ReactNative app and trying to implement Facebook login. 
So I generated the hash key with the following commande:

`keytool -exportcert -alias androiddebugkey -keystore "C:\Users\user\.android\debug.keystore" | C:\openssl-0.9.8e_X64\bin\openssl sha1 -binary | C:\openssl-0.9.8e_X64\bin\openssl base64` 
I put the generated key in the facebook developer console. 
I configured correctly my Package name and Class name. When I try to login on the Android App I get "facebook key hash does not match any stored key hashes"

So any suggestion to fix this ? Thank you

Comment: it should display a key hash that is missing from facebook developer console. can you try adding this new key hash and test again?

Comment: I never got the hash to works in dev mode. Try your facebook login with an release/production mode.